# How can I return the data submitted from a jQuery Ajax request?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm really lost on how to return a value previously submitted to a PHP file with AJAX jquery. I am just starting to learn jquery so I am still struggling with concepts a bit.

Here is my code for jquery:

```
$('#button2').click(function(e) {
    $.post("status.php", 
        {name: $('#name').val(),
        email: $('#email').val()},
        function(data){
            $('#message').html(data);
        });
    return false;
});

$('#button3').click(function(e){
    $.get({
        url: "status.php",
        data: 'information=',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#content').data(data); },
            datatype: "text"
    });
    return false;
});
```

I have the user submit their name and email to the php file, that goes through correctly and displays the output message. But I then want to have another button that displays their submission, so name: xxxxx email: xxxxx inside the #content div

Here is the PHP file

```
<?php
extract($_GET);
extract($_POST);

$data = array();

if(isset($name) && isset($email))
{
$data[$email] = $name;
echo "User information submitted.";
}

if(isset($information))
{
foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
    $name .= $key.",";
    $email .= $value.",";
}

echo $name."|".$email."\n";
}
?>
```

Our teacher has supplied us with the PHP file and we are to code the jquery and ajax. I am very lost however. Any help on how I can use $information to retrieve the users submission?

Comment: just a comment, using `extract()` on user input is bad, since you are trusting the user input to be 100% what you expect. can you use additional libraries or you need to use only jQuery? If you can, I recommend you to use http://phery-php-ajax.net it will make AJAX and DOM manipulation using PHP and jQuery a breeze

Answer (score 0):

Your not requesting your `$name` and `$email` variables in your PHP file. Add this to the top:

```
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
```

On a side note your $('#button3') is using $.post and you are using `type:"GET"`. You will need to make a choice on what you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for button3 handler, you should not use $.post, use $.get instead.

Then you can remove type: ''GET'